# Is it possible to verify and prove the decryption of an FHE cyphertext without the verifier knowing the key with zkProof?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, homomorphic-encryption

Suppose Bob encrypts a plaintext($p$) with an FHE scheme and a key($k$), then sends the $c$ to Alice.
Alice wants to know the plaintext but can't trust that Bob won't send a different string.

Can Bob prove that the $p$ he sends to Alice is a valid decryption of $c$ using zkSNARKs or another zk proof without revealing the $k$?

Comment: To make it more clear; FHE schemes are public key encryptions, so, Bob uses his public key or Alice?

Comment: I think "[Proof of plaintext knowledge](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-53015-3_17)" is what you are looking for, though I doubt what I have linked is the state of the art.

Comment: @kelalaka although the question could be more clear, some FHE schemes are not public key schemes, e.g., TFHE, FINAL, FHEW... (But there is a black-box transformation that turns any symmetric FHE scheme into a public key one).

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira ok thanks. I need to read more and more.